# Sorting Python dictionary based on nested dictionary values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How do you sort a Python dictionary based on the inner value of a nested dictionary?

For example, sort `mydict` below based on the value of `context`:

```
mydict = {
    'age': {'context': 2},
    'address': {'context': 4},
    'name': {'context': 1}
}
```

The result should be like this:

```
{
    'name': {'context': 1}, 
    'age': {'context': 2},
    'address': {'context': 4}       
}
```

Comment: Do you want a list output? or a dictionary output?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mydict = {
        'age': {'context': 2},
        'address': {'context': 4},
        'name': {'context': 1}
}
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['context']))
OrderedDict([('name', {'context': 1}), ('age', {'context': 2}), ('address', {'context': 4})])
```