# How to sort a Python dictionary by value?

Tags: python, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python how do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary)
>   [Sorting Python dictionary based on nested dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753660/sorting-python-dictionary-based-on-nested-dictionary-values)

I have dictionary of the form as mentioned below:

```
a_dict = { 'e': (1, 100), 'a': (2, 3) }
```

I am unable to sort it by the second element of the tuple. The resultant dictionary will appear as below:

```
a_dict = { 'a': (2, 3), 'e': (1, 100) }
```

Comment: @Tichodroma: that's a list of dictionaries, this is just *one* dictionary, not in a list.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Dictionaries can't be sorted as such, but you can sort their contents:

```
sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda (k, (v1, v2)): v2)
sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])    # Python 3
```

You can put the results into a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (since 2.7):

```
OrderedDict(sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda (k, (v1, v2)): v2))
OrderedDict(sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])    # Python 3
```

Comment: The argument unpacking done in your lambda will only work in Python 2.x. In Python 3 you'll need to do `key=lambda k, v : v[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are using **list of dictionaries**. Sorting the dict by key:

```
mydict = {'carl':40,
          'alan':2,
          'bob':1,
          'danny':3}

for key in sorted(mydict.iterkeys()):
    print "%s: %s" % (key, mydict[key])

alan: 2
bob: 1
carl: 40
danny: 3
```

If you want to sort a dict by values, please see [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: What list of dictionaries are you referring to? The code in the question has a dictionary with tuples as values, and no lists at all.

Comment: Of course you're right. I made a stupid mistake.