# Sort python dictionary based on a given column in an array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following kind of dictionary

```
import operator
my_dict = {'a':np.array((1,2)),'b':np.array((3,4))}
```

and I need to sorted based on the  1st column of the arrays. I can sort this other dictionary

```
my_dict2 = {'a':np.array((1)),'b':np.array((3))}
```

using

```
sorted(my_dict2.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

but trying the same approach with my_dict, i.e.

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

throws the error message

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have tried to play with the argument in itemgetter, but I cannot order my_dict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a Python dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932729/how-to-sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to use operator to get subscripted values. So what I did was this:

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0],reverse=True)
```

Explanation:
`x[1][0]` means you are taking the 1 and 3 out of (**1**,2) and (**3**,4).
`x[1][1]` means you are taking the 2 and 4 out of (1,**2**) and (3,**4**).
`x[0]` is the same as `itemgetter(0)` which will sort by a and b, which is the keys of your dictionary.