# Requesting for clarification on sorting dictionary with sorted lambda

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I am requesting clarification on the use of sorted lambda for sorting dictionaries. I have referenced these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value/613218#613218) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932729/how-to-sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value) in making my code which works fine, but am interested in understanding how it actually works.

```
'Unf': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}, 
'Ale': {'idf': 3.1179499062782403, 'den': 0.0041841004184100415}, 
'No ': {'idf': 3.1179499062782403, 'den': 0.008620689655172414}, 
One': {'idf': 3.1179499062782403, 'den': 0.005319148936170213}, 
'but': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}, 
'Bio': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}, 
'Wen': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}, 
'Lar': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}, 
'Ana': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}, 
'Adv': {'idf': 0, 'den': 0.0}}
```

this is the sorting code

```
newdict = dict(sorted(values.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1]['idf'], item[1]['den']), reverse=True))
newdict = dict(sorted(values.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1][0], item[1][1]), reverse=True))
```

for `item: (item[1]['idf'], item[1]['den']` what exactly is the `[1]` index referring to? is it referring to the values(my inner dictionary) returned by `values.items`?

If so, if i change the index to `[0]` I would be getting the dictionary key instead?
Additionally, how would I go about sorting this if I were to use `operator.itemgetter` instead?

Thank you very much for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

turns out `values.items()` returns a dict item which is iterable, hence the ability to use an index on it.

Reference from:
https://towardsdatascience.com/sorting-a-dictionary-in-python-4280451e1637