# How do i sort a dictionary by a 'subkey' in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Could i get some guidance on how to do this.

Variable

```
people = {'adam': {'distance': 14, 'age': 22, 'height': 1.3}, 'charles': {'distance': 3, 'age': 37, 'height': 1.4}, 'jeff': {'distance': 46, 'age': 42, 'height': 1.6}}
```

My Intended output after sorting the people variable by the subkey 'distance'

```
people = {'charles': {'distance': 3, 'age': 37, 'height': 1.4}, 'adam': {'distance': 14, 'age': 22, 'height': 1.3}, 'jeff': {'distance': 46, 'age': 42, 'height': 1.6}}
```

Comment: Creating a *new* dict based the sorted key/value pairs of the original list is fairly simple. Reordering the keys of an existing `dict` is a bit tedious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting Python dictionary based on nested dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753660/sorting-python-dictionary-based-on-nested-dictionary-values)

Comment: `OrderedDict` is mostly obsolete as of Python 3.6.  See [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/5987)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```py
people = dict(sorted(people.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['distance']))
```

or

```py
people = {k: v for k, v in sorted(people.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['distance'])}
```

Answer (score 4):

Most answers provide a way to create a *new* dictionary based the contents of the old. If you want to simply reorder the keys of the existing dictionary, you can do something similar:

```
for k in sorted(people, key=lambda x: people[x]['distance']):
    people[k] = people.pop(k)
```

When a key is removed, it is also removed from the iteration order. Adding it back makes it the last key in the iteration order. Repeat this for *every* key, and you redefine the iteration order of the keys. This works because `sorted` completes its iteration over the `dict` before the `for` loop starts modifying it.

Comment: hmm. @chepner This is really interesting! Thanks! Space vs time considerations would come into play at this point vs the accepted answer i guess. I cant say which solution is the better tbh (vs the accepted) so i'll let others weigh in, though both would solve my problem.

Comment: Time should be comparable. Memory usage is probably comparable. The main difference is if, for example, you expect to pass a dict to a function and have it sorted after the function returns, like `inplace_dict_sort(d)`.

Answer (score -1):

try the following code:

```
people = {'adam': {'distance': 14, 'age': 22, 'height': 1.3}, 'charles': {'distance': 3, 'age': 37, 'height': 1.4}, 'jeff': {'distance': 46, 'age': 42, 'height': 1.6}}
people = dict(sorted(people.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['distance'], reverse=False))
print(people)
```

Output:

```
people = {'charles': {'distance': 3, 'age': 37, 'height': 1.4}, 'adam': {'distance': 14, 'age': 22, 'height': 1.3}, 'jeff': {'distance': 46, 'age': 42, 'height': 1.6}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Pranta, This aligns with an answer i just accepted.